# Fortigate Monitoring with API via Grafana

Tags: api, prometheus, grafana, fortigate

As I mentioned in the title, I want to monitor Fortigate firewall with Grafana using API.
But i'm stuck about that... I tried it with Prometheus but always getting an error like;
"server returned HTTP status 429 Too Many Requests"
Actually i'm not sending any request to Fortigate and it always seems as "Down" in Prometheus :|
So do you actually know that how can i do that? I also tried to find a way from web but they all say SNMP and Exporter that's not enough for me...

I tried some configurations in Prometheus like adding my login credentials into prometheus.yml but they didn't work i'm getting 429 error..

[image: My prometheus.yml configuration]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What is shown on `/api/v2/monitor/system/interface` of your fortigate? I have doubts that it is [expected by Prometheus format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion i wasn't know that :) 

and it's shows a output like below;

{
  "http_method":"GET",
  "revision":"1685604286.491689",
  "results":{
    "port1":{
      "id":"port1",
      "name":"port1",
      "alias":"",
      "mac":"00:00:00:00:00:00",
      "ip":"192.168.100.61",
      "mask":24,
...

But i think even while i am using API i have to use FortiExporter, so i think that is the actual problem but i'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. Actual problem is than this is not metrics, but rather some json. You need something to expose metrics to Prometheus in expected format.

Comment: I see and thank you again :) after some search ı realized something too.. ı have to issue a SSL to Firewall maybe that's is the another answer of my problem.